# What is Core Data doing with my manually written @NSManaged properties. I get the entity not key value compliment

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In core data I have set my entities to Category/Extension mode.

In my xdatamodel view I have created some properties and relationships.

I tried to add another property to one of my generated entity file but I can't seem to access this property when I create a new object.

Here is my example:

I know that Core Data generates a String property for my object, let's call it a car object like so.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

Extension Car {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Sellable>

    @NSManaged public var name: String?

}
```

Very simple right? I do not create that file but I know this is what CoreData auto-generates.

Now when I try to write my "Car+CoreDataClass.swift" to add a property like this here below:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


@objc(Car)
public class Car: SomeParentClassThatInheritsFromNSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var nameTest: String?

}
```

I cannot set my instance's property value with someCarInstance.setValue("End of Line buddy!", forKey: "nameTest")

### I get this error with the setValue function :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity Car is not key value coding-compliant for the key "nameTest".'

### and this is the error I get with the object oriented way with someCarInstance.nameTest = "You too buddy." :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Car setNameTest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000aeb20' (note here, I create an NSManagedObject and have to cast is to a Car entity to get the object oriented functions and naming convention. So CoreData does see it but its not managing it.

Is this something that should never be done and why? Originally, I tried to create this property in my parent(super) class but like you see, I tested this directly in the class itself and I get the same errors. Is this something CoreData is not supposed to look in my Car class file for @NSManaged properties? In my mind that should have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `@NSManaged` property, that property **must** be declared in the managed object model.

With `@NSManaged` you're saying that this property will be managed by Core Data. Core Data can't do that unless it knows about the property. It doesn't know about the property unless it's in the managed object model.

If you want this to be managed by Core Data, you need to add it to the data model.

If you don't want this to be managed by Core Data, get rid of the `@NSManaged`.

But-- as you are finding-- you can't just declare that it's `@NSManaged` unless you include it in the data model.

Comment: Then if I want all my entities to have a recordName property, I can’t just create an extension for my NSManagedObject classes? I have to add it to all my entities in my xcdata model view? I’m disapointed, this is not really swift like.

Comment: That's how Core Data works. You either add it to each entity, or you use entity inheritance to create it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this comes up because the Code it's self is ok but the Core Data container / SQLite table is already created on your dev machine without the new entity. Try deleting anything in ~/Library/Application Support/*your app's name* and then run it again.

Comment: You mean that deleting the complete App from the simulator does not fix this? Or do you mean the MacOS version that I am not building. I'm only building the iOs 10 version for now on iPhone 7 Simulator, I get the same thing when building to my iPhone 7 device though even after deleting the App.

Comment: I even tried to delete the app from the iPhone 7, reset the phone, clean folder, then restart Xcode and then try to build again. Same thing over and over.